# Manage test execution with Maven (and Spring Boot?)

Tags: spring, maven, maven-surefire-plugin

I'm starting to write integration tests in a Spring Boot web app with MockMVC and I added the surefire plugin to my pom to execute tests during the maven build.

But now that I removed the plugin, it is still executed during build and I don't know why.

Any suggestion?

Comment: Well test are always executed yeah unless you skip them.

Comment: Maybe something was wrong before I added surefire then, because tests weren't executed automatically.

Comment: @FrancescoPapagno, Please use your maven goal as mvn clean install -DskipTests=true

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Answer to your Question**

1. spring-boot-starter-parent pom has a built-in configuration for [Surefire plugin](https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-parent/1.3.2.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-parent-1.3.2.RELEASE.pom) to run all test classes even though if you haven't included in the dependency in your POM.
2. Best way to skip this, you can give the name of Test Class as  **DemoController** which is not recognized as a matching configuration, you should rename it as **DemoControllerTest** or **DemoControllerTests**.
3. You can use these commands for your safer side.

   > ```
   > mvn clean install -DskipTests spring-boot:run
   > mvn clean install -Dmaven.test.skip=true spring-boot:run
   > ```